# Copy range of cells in column until blank cell, and paste into new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a column of data in which the range (e.g. how many rows of data there'll be) will eventually vary for each new sheet that a user creates.

On one sheet, the range in B may be from B3:B7, on another, it may be from B3:B22 for example.

I want a Macro that copies the data from the range B3:Bn, with n being the last row before there is a blank cell in the next row. For example, Copy B4:B7, and in B8 there is a blank cell. I want to paste this range into another workbook, in column C.

I'm only a beginner in VBA and have not gotten far with the code. I have tried several iterations of a loop but it doesn't really work.

This is the weak code i have so far. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub main()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("B3")
    Do While r.Value <> ""
        Range("C").Value = r.Value
        Set r = r.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Find the last row and create the range to copy. [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) will get you started.

Answer (score 5):

See this is a Simple code to get you started. Change the Names accordingly

```
Sub main()

Dim wba As Workbook
Dim wbb As Workbook

Set wba = Workbooks("Workbook A")
Set wbb = Workbooks("Workbook B")

with wba.Worksheets("Worksheet in A")
      .Range("B3", .Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Copy
End With

wbb.Worksheets("Worksheet in B").Range("C3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

A is the workbook with Data, B where you have to copy.

Change the sheet names on both Workbooks, and `Range("B3", Range("B1").End(xlDown))` will select the range till a blank cell.

Comment: I think this is a great start - however, when I try to run it, I get a "Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range" error

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: It doesn't give me a specific line, an error message pops up with "Subscript out of range"

Comment: When the Error Window pops up, select Debug, it will show you which line is causing the Error.

Comment: Line 9: wba.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Copy

Comment: line looks correct to me. Make sure the Sheet Name is Correct and there is data in the range B3:Bn

Comment: There's an error in line 9. I think it should read `Range(wba.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3"),wba.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")).End(xlDown)).Copy`

Comment: That should not result in an error, though you are right, i should have used complete reference. I will Edit the Answer now.

Comment: @LJed , I have made a change in the line, See if it works now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add one thing to Mikku's code. Instead of xlDown, in this case xlUp might be better. Because there might be one cell blank and next cell is not. When looking for last row, xlUp is good practice.

```
wba.Worksheets("Worksheet in A").Range("B3", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
```

Comment: You are right, but in the question User is not asking for the `LastRow`, he is asking for the row before the Blank cell. Read the Question again, This is what I Understood.

Comment: @Aman: to be on a safer side you have to fully qualify the cells. `wba.Worksheets("Worksheet in A").Range("B3", wba.Worksheets("Worksheet in A").Range("B" & wba.Worksheets("Worksheet in A").Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy` See the link below the question. It explains about qualifying the range.

Comment: @Mikku The user did not specifically said last row but the 1st sentence makes it clear that it is last row. But then I guess lets see what the user has to say :)

Comment: I am not asking for the LastRow, rather, copying the range before there is a blank cell. For example, B3:B23 have values, but if there is a blank cell in B24, I would stop at B23 and copy B3:B23 to the C column of the other workbook.

Comment: It is clear enough, so Mikku's code fits perfect to your aim.